# Can I use reflection to get the base property that has been overridden via the new keyword?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5

I'm working with some code which uses custom attributes for validation. I am trying to overwrite a validated property from the base class in a child class so it uses the same name for binding purposes in our generic controls, but doesn't have the validation attribute.

```
public interface IBaseClass
{
    [TestAttribute]
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IChildClass : IBaseClass
{
    new string Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass : IBaseClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass, IChildClass
{
    public new string Id { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that when our validation framework uses reflection to get the value, it is returning the child value instead of the base value.

For example,

- BaseClass.Id = null
- ChildClass.Id = "B"

Using the `PropertyInfo` for `BaseClass.Id`, I receive the value from `ChildClass.Id`.

Is it possible to use reflection to get `BaseClass.Id` rather than `ChildClass.Id` when looking at an object of type `ChildClass`?

Here's some sample code you can paste into a command line app to see what I am trying to do. I added comments with what I get vs what is Expected.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");

        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
        c.Id = "B";

        foreach (Type interfaceType in GetInterfaces<IChildClass>())
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in interfaceType.GetProperties())
            {
                Attribute[] attribs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(p, typeof(TestAttribute));
                foreach (TestAttribute v in attribs)
                {
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        object val = p.GetValue(c, new object[0]);

                        // Put breakpoint here
                        v.Validate(val);

                        // p.ReflectedType is IBaseClass, so I would expect
                        // val to be BaseClass.Id (null), however it is instead
                        // returning me ChildClass.Id ("B")

                        // Can I use reflection to get BaseClass.Id here,
                        // without hardcoding any types?

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IList<Type> GetInterfaces<B>()
    {
        List<Type> interfaces = new List<Type>();
        interfaces.Add(typeof(B));

        Type[] values = typeof(B).GetInterfaces();

        foreach (Type t in values)
        {
            interfaces.Add(t);
        }

        return interfaces;
    }
}


public interface IBaseClass
{
    [TestAttribute]
    string Id { get; set; }
}

// for sample purposes, removing inheritance from IBaseClass here
// gets me the desired result, however this is not an option in 
// the application I am working on. This base interface must remain on the 
// child interface
public interface IChildClass : IBaseClass
{
    new string Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass : IBaseClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass, IChildClass
{
    public new string Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute() { }

    public void Validate(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return;
    }
}
```

Note : Question has gone through a couple of iterations as I've tried to sort through the code framework I'm working on, and reproduce a simple example of what I am trying to do. I think I finally have a good working code sample showing what I get vs what I want.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `PropertyInfo` from the base class? That ought to work.

Comment: @SLaks The PropertyInfo is obtained using `interfaceType.GetProperty(validationAttribute.AssociatedPropertyName)`. I think that should point to the base `PropertyInfo` since it's only the base class interface that contains the attribute? The `ChildClass` has it's own interface that overwrites using the `new` keyword as well : `new string Id { get; set; }`. If I check the `propertyInfo.DeclaringType` and `propertyInfo.ReflectedType` it tells me it's the `BaseClass` interface.

Comment: how are you extracting the `PropertyInfo` ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I've edited my question with some code that can be pasted into a command prompt window to see what I am getting vs what I am expecting.

Comment: what i think you cannot as you are calling via interface type and `new` will cause the property of child class to be hidden, may be possible but not in my knowledge

Comment: @EhsanSajjad That could very well be my answer. I am trying now to figure out a way to get the `BaseClass.Id` now without hardcoding any types, but I may have to accept that it is not possible and implement a different solution. I was hoping someone on SO might know the answer to this question to save me a lot of trial and error :)

Comment: Yeah i also hope someone more knowledgeable than us may comeup with some solution, let's see :)

Comment: @Rachel: You need to get the `PropertyInfo` from the actual base type you want it for; interfaces always bind to the most-derived class.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you, that makes sense. I think the answer to my question then is based on my code, I cannot. At least, not unless I want to start messing with the validation code framework built for this application to get PropertyInfo from the class rather than the interface (which I do not). I'll have to come up with a different solution for this :)

Comment: @Rachel, make the base class property a virtual property and it should correctly resolve the attribute with the current code interrogating the interface (I haven't tested); assuming the derived class overrides, not hides.

Comment: @MetroSmurf How would that help? The attribute is on the interface definition, so I don't think it would matter how it is implemented. I did test though, and it does not work. I still receive the `ChildClass.Id` rather then the `BaseClass.Id`

Comment: I should read the code sample; didn't realize the 2 interfaces both had the same property. I was thinking the derived class would pick up the base class' interface and the overriden property would be returned, but that wouldn't work either since you need the base class attribute. Delete any thought of this :)

Comment: This code is super confusing. Sometimes `IBaseClass` is an interface, sometimes it is a class. If it is a class, then why does it begin with `I`? If it is an interface, then why does it end with `Class`?  Try to make your code *easy for the reader to understand*, because then we'll spend time thinking about your problem, and not on trying to figure out what is a class, what is an interface, and what is a typo.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm sorry for the confusing code, I tried to extract the relevant bits of code from the custom library I'm working with into a sample project that reproduced my scenario without altering any of the code. I've updated my question with a better code sample demonstrating what I am getting vs what I am looking for.

Comment: Now your comments don't match your code. The comment says "PropertyInfo is for BaseClass.Id" -- absolutely it is not. It is for IBaseClass.Id.  **We can't make heads or tails of this question because it is so confusingly written**. It's impossible to know whether you've simply made a typo, or you're confused about which property info you're looking at, or what.  Ask a much more clear question. Stop naming things all the same.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If I look at `p.ReflectedType` and `p.DefinedType` where the breakpoint is set, it shows the PropertyInfo is for `IBaseClass`, so I would expect it to return me `IBaseClass.Id`. Would it help if I made a new question for it and deleted this one with it's outdated comments?

Comment: When you ask someone "where's the bug in my code?" and your code has comments that contain falsehoods, my conclusion is that the bug is *the author's false beliefs about their code*, and that the code is probably fine. Help us help you.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm sorry, I'm not understanding what falsehoods are in my code comments. I've updated to try and clarify what I am referring to. Is there a chat room I can find you in to discuss this?

Comment: Let's take a step back.  Suppose in your inner loop you instead had `object val = ((IBaseClass)c).Id;`  Tell me **what value do you believe val should have**?

Comment: Because I think your fundamental problem is that you don't understand how interface implementation works in C#.  All this stuff with reflection and attributes and whatnot is just red herrings.  `((IBaseClass)c).Id` is `"B"`, not `null`, and that's what you should get regardless of whether you use reflection or not.

Comment: @EricLippert I think I understand. I had been casting to the base class instead of the interface for testing, and `((BaseClass)c).Id` returns `null`. If I cast to the interface instead using  `((IBaseClass)c).Id`, it returns me "B". The core of my question is I wanted a generic way to retrieve `((BaseClass)c).Id` (which is null in this case) because the PropertyInfo was for `IBaseClass`. That is not going to happen though, as `IBaseClass` is also implemented by `IChildClass`. It is not specific to `BaseClass`. I'm sorry, I think I've been staring at this too long on too little sleep :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All this stuff with reflection and attributes and whatnot is red herrings. The fundamental problem is that you've got some false beliefs about how interfaces work. Let me greatly simplify your program:

```
using System;
public interface IBaseClass
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
public interface IChildClass : IBaseClass
{
    new string Id { get; set; }
}
public class BaseClass : IBaseClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
public class ChildClass : BaseClass, IChildClass
{
    public new string Id { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
        ((BaseClass)c).Id = "Base";
        c.Id = "Child";
        Console.WriteLine( ((BaseClass)c).Id);    // Base
        Console.WriteLine( ((ChildClass)c).Id);   // Child
        Console.WriteLine( ((IBaseClass)c).Id);   // Child !!!
        Console.WriteLine( ((IChildClass)c).Id);  // Child
    }
}
```

Your problem is that you believe the third line should say `Base`, but this is wrong. It should say `Child`.

When you say `class ChildClass : BaseClass, IChildClass` you are saying **please find me the best possible bindings of properties of `ChildClass` to the required members of `IChildClass`.** What does `IChildClass` require? It requires **two string properties both called Id**. The best possible binding for both is `ChildClass.Id`.

So when you have a property info in hand for `IBaseClass.Id` and ask for the value, you get `Child`, because *in `ChildClass`*, that's the best possible binding.

Now let's make it more interesting.

```
using System;
public interface IB
{
    string P { get; }
}
public interface IC : IB
{
    new string P { get;}
}
public class B : IB
{
    public string P => "B";
}
public class C : B, IC
{
    public new string P => "C";
}
public class D1 : C  // NO IC
{
    public new string P => "D1";
}
public class D2 : C, IC // YES IC
{
    public new string P => "D2";
}
public class Program
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d1 = new D1();
        var d2 = new D2();
        Console.WriteLine(((B)d1).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((C)d1).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((IB)d1).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((IC)d1).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((D1)d1).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((B)d2).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((C)d2).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((IB)d2).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((IC)d2).P);
        Console.WriteLine(((D2)d2).P);
    }
}
```

Can you predict the behaviour of this program?

This is one of the most subtle rules of C#:  **when you explicitly put an interface in the class declaration, EVERY member of that interface is re-bound to the best value.**

Comment: Thank you for explaining things in such a clear and easy to understand way! Its not the first time your answers on SO have helped me, and I doubt it will be the last :) Your simplified code sample makes the problem perfectly clear to me, and I will have to work on an alternate solution to my issue.

Comment: @Rachel: You're welcome. See my follow-up edits, and see if you can predict the behaviour of the program. You might also want to do a web search on "C# interface re-implementation". This is a subtle and often misunderstood rule!

Comment: Interesting follow-up edit. The results surprised me at first, but it makes sense when I think about it. When doing something like `((IC)d2).P`, it seems to first check if the object inherits from IC, and if not it goes to the base object and checks there. So when `d2` inherits from `IC`, it can just use d2.P. But when `d1` does not inherit directly from IC, it looks at base class of C which does inherit from IC, so it casts it as C to get IC.P value.

Comment: @Rachel: That's good reasoning, but there is a more subtle point. Suppose you had `class D : C, IC` and `C` did *not* implement `IC`. You would expect `IC.P` in `D` to refer to `D.P` of course.  Now suppose you edit `C` to implement `IC`. Would you expect the change to the *base class* to change the binding of interface methods in a *derived class*? That would be a very strange breaking change; this is a version of the *brittle base class* problem. Many seemingly-unusual design choices in C# are there to mitigate brittle base class failures.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't excately understand your question.
Just tried with your code in a console application, and I got the "val" equals "B" (which is BaseClass.Id).

The result should be BaseClass.Id in this case. The names you given "Id" are confusing here. If you use different name in ChildClass, you will see everything works with no doubt. I want to list some points here:

- The "Id" property has not been **overriden**, but **overloaded**.
- BaseClass.Id inherits IBaseClass.Id, whereas ChildClass.Id inherits IChildClass.Id. In addition, they actually have no relationship at all.
- If you want to do GetInterfaces, simply use `c.GetType().GetInterfaces()`

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I have edited my question with what I hope is a better code sample and summary. I know there is coding that isn't optimized, however I did my best to extract the code from the huge application into a small sample project without changing any of the code, and as a result some code isn't optimal.